# Losing linked list after printing

Tags: c, data-structures, printing, linked-list, void-pointers

I have the following code:

```
if (strcmp(method, "print") == 0){
            for (i = 0; i < hashtable->M; i++){
                fprintf(fout,"[%d] :", i);
                if (hashtable->v[i] != NULL)
                    while(hashtable->v[i]){
                        fprintf(fout," ");
                        ((Pair*)hashtable->v[i]->info)->fp(hashtable->v[i], fout);
                        hashtable->v[i] = hashtable->v[i]->urm;
                    }
                fprintf(fout,"\n");
            }
        }
```

In my code, when I encounter a "print" from the file, I have to print out the values stored in my hashtable. M is the size of the hashtable, while v is a void* which points to a linked list. It's all good but if I have to add some values in the hashtable and then print them, after printing I lose all the previously stored values. I think this might have to do with the fact that I'm doing this: `hashtable->v[i] = hashtable->v[i]->urm;` but even so, I don't know how to recover the values. I was thinking about something as an auxiliary pointer to the hashtable, but that failed for me. Note, the structures are as follow

```
typedef struct celulag {
  void *info;
  struct celulag *urm;
} TCelulaG, *TLG, **ALG;

typedef unsigned int (*TFHash)(const void*, size_t M, size_t range);

/* structura tabela Hash */
typedef struct {
    size_t M;
    TFHash fh;
    TLG *v;
} TH;

typedef void (*TPrint)(TLG l, FILE *g);

typedef struct {
    void *key;
    void *value;
    TPrint fp;
    int frequency;
} Pair;
```

Note that this is done in a while so the assignment would look as this: 
Add 3 values, print, add another 4 values, print. After adding the first 3 values, if I prind, it's all good, after adding the next 4 values, if I print, only the last 4 values appear. 
Can anyone help? Thank you very much.

Comment: well, you have already answered the question. Don't do `hashtable->v[i] = hashtable->v[i]->urm;` That destroys the head of the list. Use a temp variable instead.

Comment: Oops, I was doing something pretty silly, actually. Thank you for your answer. While I was trying to use an auxiliary variable, I just destroyed the normal list as well. Thank you!